# replace id value in a string by corresonding name values whuch are present in a hashmap

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string and a map as mentioned below:

I want to replace the values which are in curly braces using the values present in my map(if corresponding key present in the map else leaving it same).

```
String input = "[text{100}any text1({200})text2{300}{400}{500}not{600}]";
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("{100}", "hundred");
map.put("{200}", "two hundred");
map.put("{300}", "three hundred");
map.put("{400}", "four hundred");
map.put("{500}", "five hundred");
```

I want an output as string which should be like:

```
"[text hundred any text1 (two hundred) text2 three hundred,four hundred,five hundred not{600}]"
```

My code is:

```
String uuidString = "[text{100}any text1({200})text2{300}{400}{500}not{600}]";

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("{100}", "hundred");
map.put("{200}", "two hundred");
map.put("{300}", "three hundred");
map.put("{400}", "four hundred");
map.put("{500}", "five hundred");

String[] uuidList = uuidString.split("(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})");
String uuidValue;


for(int i=0;i<uuidList.length;i++){
    uuidValue = map.get(uuidList[i]);
    if(uuidValue != null){
        uuidList[i]=uuidValue;
    }
}
uuidString = Arrays.toString(uuidList);
System.out.println("string :"+uuidString);
```

My output :

```
string :[[text, hundred, any text1(, two hundred, )text2, three hundred, four hundred, five hundred, not, {600}, ]] but
```

I want commas only for the consecutive curly brackets and want my output like :

```
string :[[text hundred any text1 (two hundred) text2 three hundred, four hundred, five hundred not{600} ]]
```

Comment: Please pay more attention when formatting your questions - leave text as text (not just comments in the code) and then make sure your code is indented correctly. I've fixed up this question to show you want I mean.

Comment: Thanks Jon, Posted a question first time so messed it up. will be more careful from now. thanks.

Comment: Hint: use the preview. That way you can make sure it's going to look right before you post :)

Comment: Don't use `split`. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs

Answer (score 0):

Just match with

```
\{\d+?\}
```

Find the corresponding value in the hash and replace the above match with the found value.

```
String uuidString = "[text{100}any text1({200})text2{300}{400}{500}not{600}]";

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("{100}", "hundred");
map.put("{200}", "two hundred");
map.put("{300}", "three hundred");
map.put("{400}", "four hundred");
map.put("{500}", "five hundred");

Pattern numberInCurlyBrackets = Pattern.compile("\\{\\d+?\\}");
Matcher matcher = numberInCurlyBrackets.matcher(uuidString);

while(matcher.find()) {
    String replacee = matcher.group();
    String replacement = map.get(replacee);
    if (replacement != null)
        uuidString = uuidString.replace(replacee, replacement);
}
System.out.println(uuidString);
```